# Wrong row is deleted after sorting column

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a deleting issue upon sorting the columns. if I delete without sorting any column it works perfectly fine but when I sort any column and click on delete then it will delete a different row. I couldn't figure out what i am missing here. 
Here is my jQuery code.  Thanks for your help.

```
 $scope.DeleteRule = function (index) {
        var rule = $scope.midMaintenanceData[index];
        if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this rule?"))
            return false;

        midMaintDataService.deleteMidMaintRecord(rule).success(function (data) {
            validateSession(data);
            if (data.Success == true) {
                $scope.midMaintenanceData.splice(index, 1);
                showMessageDialog("Success", data.Message);

           } else {
                showMessageDialog("Error", data.Message);
            }  
        });

    };


    $scope.midMaintenanceData = [];
       $scope.sort = {
          column: '',
          descending: false
     };
```

Comment: The index of the item is different after sorting. You may have to pass the item itself to the `DeleteRule` function then find the correct index again.

Comment: I'm assuming that the `midMaintenanceData` array is not being sorted directly that only the display of said data is being sorted thus the index being sent to the delete function is not the index of the object you are looking for in the array.

Comment: I passed the item directly into DeleteRule and it works. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in the index, pass in the item to be removed instead.  Then do:

```
$scope.midMaintenanceData.splice($scope.midMaintenanceData.indexOf(item), 1);
```